# Get min/max of returned object of solver / sympy [Python]

Tags: python, sympy

I use sympy in a Python script to get the solutions of an inequality.
I would then like to get the minimum and maximum value among all the possible values returned but cannot find out how.

The type of the returned object (x_sol) is 'And'.

```
x = Symbol("x", real=True)

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

CM = Matrix([ [0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,a,b,c], [1,a,0,d,e], [1,b,d,0,x], [1,c,e,x,0] ])

x_sol = solve_univariate_inequality( det(CM) >= 0, x, S.Reals )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `xsol.as_set().boundary`:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol("x", real=True)
a, b, c, d, e = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
CM = sym.Matrix([ [0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,a,b,c], [1,a,0,d,e], [1,b,d,0,x], [1,c,e,x,0] ])
x_sol = sym.solve_univariate_inequality( sym.det(CM) >= 0, x, sym.S.Reals )

x_set = x_sol.as_set()
x_min, x_max = x_set.boundary
print('{}, {}'.format(x_min, x_max))
```

prints

```
-sqrt(77)/2 + 9/2, sqrt(77)/2 + 9/2
```

---

Knowing how people find answers is often more interesting than the answer itself. 
So here is how I found the answer above.
[IPython](https://ipython.org/) has an extremely useful
tab-completion feature. By typing `x_sol.` and pressing TAB,

```
In [129]: x_sol.[TAB]
```

IPython shows all the attributes of `xsol`:

```
x_sol.args  x_sol.as_content_primitive
x_sol.as_poly   x_sol.as_set
x_sol.assumptions0  x_sol.atoms
...
```

Typing `x_sol.as_set?` gives documentation about the attribute or method:

```
In [129]: x_sol.as_set?
Signature: x_sol.as_set()
Docstring:
Rewrite logic operators and relationals in terms of real sets.

Examples
========

>>> from sympy import And, Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> And(x<2, x>-2).as_set()
(-2, 2)
File:      ~/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sympy/logic/boolalg.py
Type:      method
```

Simply by using IPython to explore the available attributes, it was not hard to
discover that `as_set` and `boundary` yield the desired values.

Hopefully, knowing this trick will help you discover solutions to other problems more quickly in the future.